# Can't update an SQLite table with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, adt

this are the tables.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String SQL_Proveedores = "CREATE TABLE proveedores ("+_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,nombre TEXT,contacto TEXT)";
    arg0.execSQL(SQL_Proveedores);
    String SQL_productos = "CREATE TABLE productos ("+_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nombre TEXT, cat TEXT, precio TEXT, proveedor INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (proveedor) REFERENCES proveedores (ROWID))";
    arg0.execSQL(SQL_productos);
    arg0.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
}
```

this is the SQLite update statement, it's a simple update but it doesn't work, i don't know what is wrong.. the tables has a relationship.

```
    btnmodificar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {        
    try { bd.execSQL("UPDATE productos SET nombre='" + editText1.getText().toString() +"', cat='" + editText2.getText().toString()+"', precio='" + editText3.getText().toString()+"' WHERE ROWID="+ registros.getInt(0));                           

         }
                                                }
            });
```

Comment: As an aside, please don't build an SQL statement like this. Use [`SQLiteDatabase.update()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your update query with this

```
 bd.execSQL("UPDATE productos SET nombre='" + editText1.getText().toString() +"', cat='" + editText2.getText().toString()+"', precio='" + editText3.getText().toString()+"'" + "WHERE ROWID="+ registros.getInt(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"UPDATE productos SET nombre='" + editText1.getText().toString() +"', cat='" + editText2.getText().toString()+"', precio='" + editText3.getText().toString()+"' WHERE ROWID="+ registros.getInt(0));
```

for the above line of code, in where condition your referring to `ROWID`. Which is not there in `productos` table. please check

Even below sql is also wrong please read about foreign key concept and database too.

`"CREATE TABLE productos ("+_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nombre TEXT, cat TEXT, precio TEXT, proveedor INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (proveedor) REFERENCES proveedores (ROWID))";`